# attachEvent and addEventListener both are not working in IE 11 and Edge

Tags: javascript

I have tried script below and it works perfectly to both Firefox and Chrome, however, when it comes to IE, my console log didn't appear any error or message when i launch the page that hold this code below :

```
if(window.attachEvent){

   window.attachEvent( "message",
          function (e) {
             window.location.assign(e.data);
          });
}
else{
   window.addEventListener( "message",
          function (e) {
             window.location.assign(e.data);
          },
          false);

}
```

Comment: you need HTML5 <!DOCTYPE html> doctype

Comment: If I can recall correctly, `attachEvent` hasn't been supported since IE10. In the older IE's it is supported, but the event name should be prefixed with `on`.

Comment: @ankit_sharma I've checked with my DOM Explorer, there is <!DOCTYPE html> on the very first line

Comment: @Teemu yes, hence I've put the If else statement to catch if attachEvent is not supported, use addEventListener. But still couldn't find out why IE is only browser not working with it, and there is no error display on the console

Comment: I've no clue, PostMessages are supported since IE8 ... How about CORS? Is it enabled in the Internet Options?